# pythontex puzzle

Tags: tikz-matrix, pythontex

For large matrices it is too difficult for me to type the `tikz` matrix expression. I have written some code in Python that does that for me. The code prints out the `tikz` expression which I then copy/paste to the `tex` file. But then I found that there is a brilliant package called `pythontex` that actually allows the user to run the code directly from the tex file. So I copied my code over to a tex file and run it... unfortunately it does not work. It seems to think I have missed a bracket:

```
Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.454 \end{tikzpicture}
```

I know I have not since exactly the same code prints an expression that compiles in a `tex` file.

This is the `tex` file with `pythontex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric,calc,matrix,math}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
import numpy as np

def indexTable(a):
    l = 1
    for x in a:
        l=l*x
    t = np.zeros((l,len(a)))

    for i in range(l):
        index=i
        for j in range(len(a)):
            t[i,-j-1]=index%a[-j-1]+1
            index = index // a[-j-1]
            
    return t

def printTensor(a,ai,b,bi,f):
    t = indexTable(a)
    s = indexTable(b)

    l , h = t.shape
    r , u = s.shape

    print(r"\begin{tikzpicture}")
    print(r"\matrix(m) [matrix of nodes, column sep=3ex, nodes={minimum height=5ex, anchor=center}] { ")
    for i in range(u):
        for j in range(h):
            print(r" & ",end='')
        for j in range(r-1):
            print(r" \mbox{\tiny $%s = %d$} & " % (bi[i],s[j,i]),end='')
        print(r" \mbox{\tiny $%s = %d$} \\" % (bi[i],s[r-1,i]))

    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(h):
            print(r" \mbox{\tiny $%s = %d$} &" % (ai[j],t[i,j]),end='')
        for j in range(r-1):
            eq = f(t[i,:],s[j,:])
            print(" " + eq + " & ",end='')   
        eq = f(t[i,:],s[r-1,:])         
        print(eq, end='')
        print(r" \\")
    
    print(r"};")
    print(r"\end{tikzpicture}")

def simpleTensor(subs,sups):
    eq = r"$\tensor{X}{"

    for x in sups:
        eq = eq + "^" + str(int(x))
    
    for x in subs:
        eq = eq + "_" + str(int(x))
    
    eq = eq + "}$"

    return eq

\end{pycode}


\pyc{printTensor([2,3,2],['i','j','k'],[3,3,3],['p','q','r'],simpleTensor)}

\end{document}
```

I run `LaTeX` on `maOSCatalina` (10.15.7). I use a `TeX Live` installation. I compile the `tex` files with `Visual Studio Code` (LaTeX-Workshop is the latex extension).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can't reproduce. Try deleting all temporary files and make a clean build (for example by creating a TeX file in a new directory with a different name then rebuild or something)

Comment: Yes that works.